# Tried installing Mint 17.1 64bit, deleted Windows 8.1 boot partition when I overwrited it with the Linux boot

Tags: linux-mint, windows, dual-boot

When live-usb installing linux mint 17.1 64bit, I chose the windows 8.1 bootup partition as the bootup for linux, so when the boot menu appears and I try to run windows 8.1, it re-runs the linux menu infinitely...

So I went on the live-usb again and deleted all the stuff i used to install linux on my hard drive, and now as you might think, my computer has no way to start working.

I also have windows 7 installed alongside windows 8.1, so I was trying to get a triple boot running, and screwed up. What would be the best way to get the bootup for windows 8.1 and 7 running fine again, and just scrap linux for the time being?

Comment: For next time, may want to see this Q about dual-booting Windows 8 & Ubuntu (similar for Ubuntu-based distros like Mint, should be useful for most Linux's too especially with EFI, Secure Boot ... http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Answer (score 0):

Call your PC manufacturers support Support. I too inadvertently wiped out Win 8.1 installing Linux Mint 17.1. My screw up as I didn't pay close enough attention when the option for dual boot came up. Mine is a Dell and the Dell Rep walked me through the process of getting Win 8.1 back up through Command Prompt.
Make sure he/she knows if you changed any of the BIOS configuration.
Also, realize that Linux will still be on your PC, but only accessible via the installation disk, or at least that's the way it is in my case. I still need to figure out how to make it a dual boot.
Can't find anything about uninstalling Linux and doing a clean re install without messing with my partitions, another (for me) disaster waiting to happen.